# how to get an single element form an array : javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with values like this

```
arr = [ 'java', 6 ]
```

My question, is how do I get just "java" in my output

My output should be like

```
java
```

Comment: Same as with most programming languages: arr[0]

Comment: Java and Javascript are about as similar to each other as Car and Carpet.

Comment: This question is trivial and can be solved by reading the most basic introductory article on JavaScript arrays. It is unlikely to help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing; 0 for 'java', and 1 for 6.
To get `'java'`, just do `arr[0]`

Answer (score 0):

if you want you output java this is sol :

```js
var arr = [ 'java', 6 ];
alert(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays are have their indexes start at 0. 
So, `arr = [ 'java', 6 ]` contains 2 elements. And since arrays have their index start at 0, 'java' would be at the [0] index and '6' would be at the [1] index.
To access it you just need to do arr[0] and output it with, for example, `console.log(arr[0])` which is the *simplest way* to access 'java'. (e.g You can do arr[i] where i is a number with a value of 0)